# .htaccess redirect all pages and url from old domain to new domain

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

to be very honest I have zero knowledge with Regex and .htaccess

somewhere I found this code sample to redirect the user from old domain to new domain and it works fine

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But what is the issue here is when I access any page like www.old.com/courses it remains there rather of redirecting it to www.new.com/courses

It is a wordpress site and it has thousand of such sub/internal pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have those rules **before** any wordpress rules.

Comment: so these code above wordpress's rules and below `RewriteEngine On` right?